# java split string and only keep everything after a particular word

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a string that I need to split

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM X....
```

I need to split it and only keep, "FROM...." and onwards. Right now I have this, but I think it will actually get rid of the FROM string also correct?

```
String query = xyz.getQuery();
String [] newQuery = query.split("FROM");
String splitQuery = newQuery[1];
```

Comment: Couldn't you use `indexOf` and `substring` ?

Comment: why don't you just get the index of FROM and take substring then?

Comment: Try this https://regex101.com/r/nM2hE9/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why exactly do you need `regex` for this?

without regex

**Sol 1**

Add this to your code

```
String splitQuery = "FROM " + newQuery[1];
```

**Sol 2**

```
System.out.println(line.substring(line.indexOf("FROM")));
```

and if you still need `regex`

```
String line = "SELECT a, b, c FROM X....";
String pattern = "((FROM|from).*)";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

if (m.find()) {
     System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just used solution 1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting, you could try this. Assuming you only want what is written after the first `FROM` and not from any nested `FROM`:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Solution {


    public String getSubString(String s)
    {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("FROM.+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

        if(m.find())
        {
            return m.group(0);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String query = "SELECT a, b, c FROM myTable";
        Solution sol = new Solution();

        String ans = sol.getSubString(query);

        if(ans != null)
        {
            System.out.println(ans);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Not Found");
        }
    }
}
```

Aside from this a better way is to first get the starting position of `FROM` and then simply use `substring` method from that point to length of the string.

Answer (score 0):

In addition with split and possitive lookahead, so you don't get rid of "FROM".

```
@Test
public void testRegex(){

    String query = "SELECT a, b, c FROM x y z";
    String regex = "(?=FROM.*)|(?=from.*)";
    System.out.println(query.split(regex)[1]);

    assertEquals("FROM x y z", query.split(regex)[1]);
}
```

> FROM x y z